# Block in canvas dissapeared for one frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to build Snake from scratch using Javascript. But when I use the arrow keys to get it from 1 part of the canvas to the other part of the canvas it dissapears for 1 frame, how to resolve this? You can try it on: https://annedegraaff.nl/snake/

```
<canvas id="snake" width="400" height="400">

</html>

<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

var ball1X = 12.5;
var ball1Y = 12.5;  
window.onload = function() {
   canvas = document.getElementById('snake');
   canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var framesPerSecond = 60;
  setInterval(function() {
  draw();
  move();

  }, 1000/framesPerSecond);

}
function move() {
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if (ball1X < 12.5) {
     ball1X += 395;
   }else if (ball1X > 385) {
     ball1X -= 395;
   }
   if (key == 39) {
       ball1X += 10;
   }else if (key == 37) {
       ball1X -= 10;
   }else if (key == 40) {
       ball1Y += 10;
   }else if (key == 38) {
       ball1Y -= 10;
   }
  }

}
function draw() {
   canvasContext.fillStyle = 'green';
   canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
   canvasContext.fillRect(ball1X,ball1Y,10,10);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Logic error in keyEvent handler

Though not directly evident where the problem is in the given code I am assuming it is the test for edges in the `keydown` handler. There are also other ting being done incorrectly that will present additional problems and difficulties as you develop the game.

#### Your bug

In your keyboard function you test if the ball is close to the edge and if so you move it to the other size. Looks like you move it too far and thus can not be seen.

The following is a quick fix. Move the test to after the ball has been moved and make sure the the move to the other side does not put it too far so that it is moved again on the next event.

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if (key == 39) {
       ball1X += 10;
   }else if (key == 37) {
       ball1X -= 10;
   }else if (key == 40) {
       ball1Y += 10;
   }else if (key == 38) {
       ball1Y -= 10;
   }
   if (ball1X < 12.5) {
     ball1X += 400;
   }else if (ball1X > 400-12.5) {
     ball1X -= 400;
   }
 }
```

#### Other problems.

- Use `requestAnimationFrame` for animations not `setInterval`
- Key event listeners should only record the keyboard state as they have nothing to do with the game and dont know what to do with the keys pressed. The game code should use the keyboard state and its own current state to work out what to do with each key
- Use `addEventListener` add events as directly setting event can be overwritten
- Encapsulate your game inside a function so that all the variables and functions are isolated from the global names space and you can easily insert the game into any page.
- Use objects to group properties and function together. Eg you had `ballX`, `ballY` and most like will add other properties each will have a ball prefix. By creating an object named `ball` and adding properties like `x`,`y` you can get access to the balls `x`, `y` with via a reference `ball.x`, `ball.y` or `var b = ball`; b.x += 1;`. Once an object has been defined you can make many copies easily.
- Change the key handler to hold the key state of only the keys you are interested in. You only want to know if the key is down so listen to key up and down setting a flag to `true` when a key is down.

And other stuff

#### Rewrite

A quick rewrite showing a better way to implement what you had. It is a recommendation only. It is a little longer than you had it and is not the only way, but if you write like this it will be easier as the game develops.

See comments for the reasons and what does what.

```js
// create onload event handler as a function and encapsulate all variables and functions to key global name space clean 
function start(){
  // create canvas and context
  const canvas = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // formaly canvasContext;
  // get the size as we use that a lot
  const width = canvas.width;
  const height = canvas.height;
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // will call mainloop after this function (start) has run
  // create an object to hold all related properties and 
  // functions for the ball
  const ball = {  // position ball in center
     x : width / 2 | 0,   // the or zero ( | 0) rounds down to nearest integer
     y : height / 2 | 0, 
     size : 10,
     speed : 10,
     draw() {  // function to draw the ball
       ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
       ctx.fillRect(this.x - this.size / 2,this.y - this.size / 2, this.size, this.size);
     },      
     update() {  // moves the ball 
       if (keys.up    === true) { this.y -= this.speed }
       if (keys.down  === true) { this.y += this.speed }
       if (keys.left  === true) { this.x -= this.speed }
       if (keys.right === true) { this.x += this.speed }
       // get half size
       const hSize = this.size / 2;
       // check for edges and move to other side of canvas
       if(this.x + hSize < 0) { this.x += width }
       if(this.x - hSize > width) { this.x -= width }
       if(this.y + hSize < 0) { this.y += height }
       if(this.y - hSize > height) { this.y -= height }
     },
  }
  // the background function clears and displays the background
  function background(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
  }  
  // Object to hold the current keyboard state
  const keys = {
    up : false,
    down : false,
    left : false,
    right : false,
    map : new Map([ // use a Map to find keys
      [39,"right"],  // key  code and string name of keys.name
      [37,"left"],
      [40,"down"],
      [38,"up"],
     ])
  }
  // the key event listener
  function keyEvents(event){
    // get key code as a string
    const keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    // get if avalible the key name from the map
    const key = keys.map.get(keyCode); 
    // if a key is mapped set its state
    if(key){
       keys[key] = event.type === "keydown";
       event.preventDefault(); // pervent default action
    }
  }    
  // listent to the keyboard events and set the keyboard state
  ["keydown","keyup"].forEach(eventName => addEventListener(eventName, keyEvents));

// for the stackoverflow snippet we need to get focus to
  // hear any of the key events
  focus();
  


  function mainLoop(time){ // time is automatic and in ms (1/1000th second)
    background();  // call the background function that clears and displays the background
    // update and draw the ball object
    ball.update();
    ball.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // request next frame in 1/60th second
  }
}
// when loaded start the game
addEventListener("load", start);
```

```html
<canvas id="snakeCanvas" width="400" height="400">
```